# import foreign DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

So i have this DLL from a company called "Mind Media" to access their product's API and i want to include it in my c#-project but it's written in c++. I managed to get most of the exposed functions running, but 2 of them give me an AccessViolationException. Thats probably because i give the wrong parameter so my question is how to fix that.

Together with the DLL i also got a manuel and a demo-program in c++, so this is all information i have about the functions:
**From the manuel:**

> - **GetChannelInfo()** to get the info of a requested channel.
> - **GetGenericDeviceInfo()** to get info of the connected front end.

```css
bool  GetChannelInfo(
   IN  int  ChannelIndex
   IN OUT  CHANNEL_INFO  &ChannelInfo
);
```

> ***Parameters:***
> *ChannelIndex*
>     Number of the requested channel info. If the given channel number is smaller than zero, it is set to ‘0’. If it is larger     than the number of available channels of the connected device, this value is set to the maximal channel number.
> ***Note: Channel numbering starts with index ‘0’***
> *ChannelInfo*
>     Pointer to a structure where this function returns the information of requested channel.
> ***Return Value:***
>     If successful this function returns TRUE.

```css
bool  GetGenericDeviceInfo(
IN OUT  DEVICE_INFO  &DeviceInfo
);
```

> ***Parameters:***
> *DeviceInfo*
>     Pointer to a structure where this function returns the information of the connected device.
> ***Return Value:***
>     If successful this function returns TRUE.

**From the demo:**

```js
typedef bool (*DLL_GETCHANNELINFO) ( int Index, CHANNEL_INFO *chanInf );
typedef bool (*DLL_GETDEVICEINFO) ( DEVICE_INFO *devInf );

GetGenericDeviceChannelInfo = (DLL_GETCHANNELINFO) GetProcAddress( m_handle, "GetChannelInfo" );
GetGenericDeviceInfo = (DLL_GETDEVICEINFO) GetProcAddress( m_handle, "GetDeviceInfo" );


#define DEVICE_NAME_SIZE        40
#define DEVICE_SERIAL_SIZE      40
#define DEVICE_DESCRIPTION_SIZE 40
#define CONNECTION_TYPE_SIZE    40
#define CHANNEL_NAME_SIZE       40

typedef enum _INPUT_TYPE 
{
    IT_UNK                  = 0,    // Unknown
    IT_UNP                  = 1,    // Unipolar(uV)
    IT_BIP                  = 2,    // Bipolar(uV)
    IT_AUX                  = 3,    // Aux(mV)
    IT_BIT                  = 4     // Bit
} 
INPUT_TYPE, * PINPUT_TYPE;

typedef struct _CHANNEL_INFO
{ 
    TCHAR cName[CHANNEL_NAME_SIZE];
    DWORD dwSampleRate;
    _INPUT_TYPE InputType;   
} 
CHANNEL_INFO, *PCHANNEL_INFO;

typedef struct _DEVICE_INFO
{
    TCHAR cName[DEVICE_NAME_SIZE];
    TCHAR cSerialNumber[DEVICE_SERIAL_SIZE];        // 0-3 type, 4-5 yy, 6-9 index number from year
    TCHAR cDescription[DEVICE_DESCRIPTION_SIZE];
    TCHAR cConnectionType[CONNECTION_TYPE_SIZE];
    DWORD dwTypeID;                                 
    DWORD dwNumberOfChannels;
    bool bAuthenticated;
} 
DEVICE_INFO, *PDEVICE_INFO;


void CGENERICDEVICE_DLL_DEMODlg::OnBnClickedGetchannelinfo()
{
    // Local variables:
    int             nChannelIndex;
    CHANNEL_INFO    ciTemp;
    CString         csStr;

    // Read the channel selection of the dialog
    m_ChannelIndex.GetWindowText(csStr); 
    nChannelIndex = atoi(csStr);
    //...
    
    // Load channel info from the DLL and show it in a information popup
    if (GetGenericDeviceChannelInfo(nChannelIndex,&ciTemp))
    {
        //...
    }
}

void CGENERICDEVICE_DLL_DEMODlg::OnBnClickedInit()
{
    // Local variables:
    DEVICE_INFO diDeviceInfo;
    //...
    GetGenericDeviceInfo(&diDeviceInfo);
}
```

---

so here is what i did, trying to copy it in c# (mind that i don't have any experience with or knowledge of c++ or pointers):

```cs
class Program
{
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var channel = new CHANNEL_INFO();
        var ptr = (IntPtr)(&channel);
        var chanpnt = &channel;
        var device = new DEVICE_INFO();
        var pt = (IntPtr)(&device);
        var devpnt = &device;
        //...
        var test4 = GetChannelInfo(1, ref chanpnt);
        var test5 = GetDeviceInfo(ref devpnt);
    }

    public enum INPUT_TYPE
    {
        IT_UNK = 0, // Unknown
        IT_UNP = 1, // Unipolar(uV)
        IT_BIP = 2, // Bipolar(uV)
        IT_AUX = 3, // Aux(mV)
        IT_BIT = 4      // Bit
    }

    public struct CHANNEL_INFO
    {
        char cName;
        uint dwSampleRate;
        INPUT_TYPE InputType;
    }

    public struct DEVICE_INFO
    {
        char cName;
        char cSerialNumber;
        char cDescription;
        char cConnectionType;
        uint dwTypeID;
        uint dwNumberOfChannels;
        bool bAuthenticated;
    }

    [DllImport("GenericDeviceInterfaceDLL_x64.dll")]
    public extern static unsafe bool GetChannelInfo(int index, ref CHANNEL_INFO* channelInfo);

    [DllImport("GenericDeviceInterfaceDLL_x64.dll")]
    public extern static unsafe bool GetDeviceInfo(ref DEVICE_INFO* deviceInfo);
}
```

i couldn't just do `GetChannelInfo(1, ref &channel);` because then i get

> [CS1510](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/roslyn.query?appId=roslyn&k=k(CS1510)): A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable

i tried to change all the chars to strings but then i get

> [CS0208](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/roslyn.query?appId=roslyn&k=k(CS0208)): Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Program.DEVICE_INFO')

if i run it the way it is now i get `System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.` for both methods

googling told me that the only solution is to contact the maintainers of the code and maybe send them a memory dump of the application, but i'm probably just doing something wrong.
so how can i fix this?

Comment: In your struct declarations you need to look at the arrays and declare them accordingly

Comment: what do you mean @DavidHeffernan? i don't have any arrays in there and in the demo it says TCHAR (if you are reffering to that) which is, as far as i understand it also just a character

Comment: [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 40)] public string cName;  Same for the device_info members.  And the struct requires the [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] attribute.  It might be CharSet.Ansi, it is not obvious from the C++ declaration.  Ideally you verify that sizeof(CHANNEL_INFO) in the C++ code is the same as Marshal.Sizeof(typeof(CHANNEL_INFO)) in the C# code.

Comment: You don't have arrays in your structs in C# but that's the mistake. Look at the C declarations and observe the arrays.